# Moment.js buga ao trabalhar com datas da noite para a manhã

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hoje me deparei com um problema no momento de testar as diferenças de horas na biblioteca do `moment.js`.

Ela funciona perfeitamente, porém quando adiciono um trabalho da noite até o dia seguinte ele me traz um horário negativo.

Codigo:

```js
$("#time2").keyup(function() {
  var valor = $(this).val().length;
  if (valor === 5) {
    var hrF = document.getElementById("time2").value;
    var hrIni = document.getElementById("time1").value;
    var ms = moment(hrF, "HH:mm").diff(moment(hrIni, "HH:mm"));
    var d = moment.duration(ms);
    var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + ":" + moment.utc(ms).format("mm");
    document.getElementById("timedif").value = s; //Jogar o valor em um terceiro campo do tipo time
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

<div class=''>
  <input type="text" class="form-control tracker1" name="time1" id="time1" placeholder="12:00" data-timepicker>
</div>

<div class='mr-2'>
  <input type="text" class="form-control tracker1" id="time2" placeholder="12:00" data-timepicker>
</div>
<div class='mr-2'>
  <input type="text" class="form-control tracker1" id="timedif" readonly>
</div>
```

Comment: para que essa conta seja feito corretamente precisa também da data com a hora, exemplo: `1999-01-01 13:00|1992-01-01 01:00` sem a data o cálculo fica errado !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz a verificação, caso o resultado seja negativo, ele irá adicionar mais 1 dia (24h) ao resultado, fazendo o cálculo de forma correta.
Segue código abaixo:

```js
$("#time2").keyup(function() {
  var valor = $(this).val().length;
  if (valor === 5) {

    var hrF = document.getElementById("time2").value;
    var hrIni = document.getElementById("time1").value;
    var ms = moment(hrF, "HH:mm").diff(moment(hrIni, "HH:mm"));
    var d = moment.duration(ms);
    if (d < 0) { //trecho adicionado
      d = d.add(1, 'd');
    }
    var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + ":" + moment.utc(ms).format("mm");

    document.getElementById("timedif").value = s; //Jogar o valor em um terceiro campo do tipo time

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

<div class=''>
  <input type="text" class="form-control tracker1" name="time1" id="time1" placeholder="12:00" data-timepicker>
</div>

<div class='mr-2'>
  <input type="text" class="form-control tracker1" id="time2" placeholder="12:00" data-timepicker>
</div>
<div class='mr-2'>
  <input type="text" class="form-control tracker1" id="timedif" readonly>
</div>
```

Comment: Show, funcionou perfeitamente! Valeu pelo norte.

Answer (score 0):

Como você não está especificando uma data, ele vai assumir a data atual. Acredito que o correto seja você disponibilizar a data/hora. Segue abaixo um exemplo:

> JavaScript

```
$("#time2,#time1").change(function() {
    if(!$('#time1').val() || !$('#time2').val())
    return;

    var valor = $(this).val().length;
  var ms = moment($('#time2').val()).diff(moment($('#time1').val()));

  var d = moment.duration(ms);
  var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + ":" + moment.utc(ms).format("mm") ; 
  $("#timedif").val(s); //Jogar o valor em um terceiro campo do tipo time
});
```

> HTML

```
<div class=''>           
    <input type="datetime" class="form-control tracker1" name="time1" id="time1" placeholder="12:00" data-timepicker>
</div>

<div class='mr-2'>
    <input type="datetime" class="form-control tracker1" id="time2" placeholder="12:00" data-timepicker>
</div>
<div class='mr-2'>
    <input type="text" class="form-control tracker1" id="timedif" readonly>
</div>
```

> JSFiddler

https://jsfiddle.net/syhu4tg6/

Comment: Nessa abordagem de apenas colocar o resultado para positivo vamos ter um erro de cálculo. Já que em um cenário de início às 22h e fim às 05h, a diferença que vai dar é de 17h (pelo seu código), quando o real é de 7h. Para ajeitar isso falta somar mais 24h no resultado, daí vamos ter ```-17 + 24 = 7```.

Comment: Lucas, você tem razão.

Comment: @LucasAyrosa editei a resposta.